# Animate (pulse, glow) CPTPlotSymbol using Core Plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, plot, core-plot

I would like to animate (pulse, glow) the following plot symbol. What is the best way to achieve the desired behavior. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot animate a plot symbol. What you can do is put a plot space annotation over the highlighted point. Make a custom `CPTLayer` subclass that draws your symbol shape and use that for the annotation's content layer. Animate the symbol layer using standard Core Animation methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about glowing but, I do that there is a method(that I can't seem to recall) that you can call that will do just that! It's like CGResize or something, it exists! Don't lose hope. Sorry i'm not able to help more.

Actually for glowing you could animate it with animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: then the picture you want to glow just make it dark to bright then bright to dark, then setAnimationRepeatCount:0 to it'll repeat! This way is a bit verbose but it'd work! Best of luck :]